# How to validate date and time on the client side like Chrome does, using Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, asp.net-web-api, flutter-http

I have a `Flutter Web application`, and I want to validate the date and time of the `Client` side, just like `Chrome` or `Whatsapp` does. To do this, I decided to send in each request the current date and time within the `headers`, and validate it on the `Server`, but for some reason I received the error `Refused to set unsafe header "date"` in the `browser console`, and the field `date` is not found within the `headers` on the `Server` side. Could someone provide me with the correct way to do what I want, or the solution to my problem?

I have already searched several answers but I still do not have the solution, for example [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725403/flutter-web-http-request-is-unable-to-send-my-header-named-cookie-is-there-a) of the most recent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header name `Date` is reserved - only the browser may set it. See Section 4.6.2 of the XMLHttpRequest spec for the complete list. Can you change your header name to, say, `Request-Date`? (Of course, it seems it would be easy to forge.)

Also, rather than sending the value as a header, you could send it as a query parameter of a GET, or in the body of a POST (form or JSON).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck for a whole day not knowing what to do. Thank you